# My super class variables are null when accessing them from childclass

Tags: java

I am having a problem when trying to print my ticket(child class) which is all my superclass variables are null or zero not initialized.
this is my superclass:-

```
public class movie {
    protected int movieID;
    protected String movieTitle;

movie(){};
    movie(int movieID , String movieTitle ){
        this.movieID = movieID;
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;

    }


}
```

this is my childclass

```
public class ticket extends movie{
    private int Number_of_ticket;
    private int show_number ;
    ticket(int Number_of_ticket , int show_number){

        this.Number_of_ticket = Number_of_ticket;
        this.show_number = show_number;


    }
    public void print_the_tacket(){
        System.out.println("movie id is " + super.movieID);
        System.out.println("movie name is " + super.movieTitle);
        System.out.println("number of the ticket is " + Number_of_ticket);
        System.out.println("show number is  " + show_number);

    }
}
```

the main

```
 public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            movie MyMovie = new movie(1234, "spiderman");

            ticket myticket  = new ticket(34 , 334);
            myticket.print_the_tacket();
        }
    }
```

my output is

```
movie id is 0
movie name is null
number of the ticket is 34
show number is  334
```

I expect when I print my ticket the movie information why I am getting null values What is wrong here? thank you in advance.

Comment: Which super constructor do you think Ticket uses?

Comment: Side note: this is not a good inheritance structure in that Ticket should most definitely ***not*** extend Movie. They are two completely different beasts and should interact in different ways, not via inheritance.

Comment: Can you tell what else methodologies can i use to make two classes interact together?

Comment: Use ***composition***, not ***inheritance***. A Ticket object should have a Movie field. That's it.

Comment: Generally a subclass should be in a "is-a" relationship with the superclass. A Ticket is not a type of Movie. However, a ticket is generally written for a specific showing of a specific movie, so the Ticket class should contain a reference to the movie being shown, along with the time/date of the ticket.

Comment: You never set those values in `ticket`, so of course they are null. Your `ticket` constructor needs those as parameters and you need to pass them to `super()`. What you did with the `new Movie()` object in `main()` is irrelevant.

Comment: @user207421 And this is why Ticket should not be a subclass of Movie. For each Movie, there are *many* Ticket objects (potentially). A Ticket should contain a reference to a movie, but it shouldn't extend movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain..

Note 1: There are 2 constructors created here. One is movie() without arguments, the other is with 2 arguments. What you extend and call is #1 not #2

```
public class movie {
  protected int movieID;
  protected String movieTitle;

  movie() { //#1 - no args, so movieID=null, movieTitle=null
    //you can debug by adding this line.
    this.movieID = 1;
    this.movieTitle = "I should not be printing this";
  } 

  movie(int movieID , String movieTitle ){ //#2 - has args.
    this.movieID = movieID;
    this.movieTitle = movieTitle;

  }
}
```

Note 2: Your problem is in ticket, when you do not write super(..) with args you are passing nothing, hence it is calling movie() without parameters. So if you are calling movie(), you get non declared variables. If you see sample above for debug you should see 1 and "I should not print this" instead to explain the scenario.

```
public class ticket extends movie{
  private int Number_of_ticket;
  private int show_number ;

  ticket(int Number_of_ticket , int show_number){
    //Not visible, but actually triggers super() and calling movie #1, not super(arg1, args2)
    //super(1,"movie")
    this.Number_of_ticket = Number_of_ticket;
    this.show_number = show_number;
  }
}
```

Note 3: You are making 2 different objects, object #1 is movie, and object #2 is ticket. To me it seems you only want 1 object which is ticket that extends movie. What happens here is that the codes are 2 different/seperated objects and they are not tied together.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        movie MyMovie = new movie(1234, "spiderman"); //#Object 1

        ticket myticket  = new ticket(34 , 334); //#Object 2
        myticket.print_the_tacket();
    }
}
```

Approach: You may want the codes to be the following way where you create movie and ticket together in ticket call. This means when you create ticket your movie must be created. In a nutshell no movie created, no tickets to issue.

```
public class Movie { //Class name should always be captialized
  protected int movieID; //you can declare final
  protected String movieTitle;

  Movie(int movieID , String movieTitle ){ //Only this
    this.movieID = movieID;
    this.movieTitle = movieTitle;

  }
}

public class Ticket extends Movie { //Captialize class
  private int Number_of_ticket; //should avoid _ and use Snakecase
  private int show_number ;

  Ticket(int Number_of_ticket , int show_number, int movieID, String movieTitle){
    super(movieId, movieTitle); //always and must create movie object
    this.Number_of_ticket = Number_of_ticket;
    this.show_number = show_number;
  }

  public void print_the_tacket(){ //should use snake case printTheTacket
    System.out.println("movie id is " + super.movieID);
    System.out.println("movie name is " + super.movieTitle);
    System.out.println("number of the ticket is " + Number_of_ticket);
    System.out.println("show number is  " + show_number);

  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ticket myticket  = new Ticket(34 , 334, 1234, "spiderman");
    myticket.print_the_tacket();
  }
}
```

Much ideal is that movie is created in ticket instead of passing 2 arguments or extending. In this case both are separated and tied and incase in future movie has also things like PG-13, GA parameters you can expand it. But i guess it's for school understanding on inheritance, your example fits for now.

```
public class Ticket { 
  private int numberOfTickets; 
  private int showNumber ;
  private Movie movie;

  Ticket(int numberOfTickets , int showNumber, Movie movie){
    this.numberOfTickets = numberOfTickets;
    this.showNumber = showNumber;
    this.movie = movie
  }

  public void printTheTacket(){ 
    System.out.println("movie id is " + movie.movieID);
    System.out.println("movie name is " + movie.movieTitle);
    System.out.println("number of the ticket is " + numberOfTickets);
    System.out.println("show number is  " + showNumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reference super in the child class, it not bound to the Movie object you created in the main().  That is why you are getting a null value. Look here when I debug the code.

[image]

If you want to access the Movie object you created in main(), you can pass it and that will work.

[image]